# Exception Value: Django Class-Based View object has no attribute 'campaignId'

Tags: python, django

I have been stuck on this for a couple of hours; I am probably missing something simple, but I am not sure.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

I recently changed the database for our Django project from MongoDB to Neo4J.  During the migration process, I am modifying some of the views, URLs, etc.

The traceback I am seeing:

```
Exception Value: 'TweetListView' object has no attribute 'campaignId'
```

Here is the full traceback and relevant code: https://gist.github.com/joefusaro/820270c1ff0999d3d3fd

**from campaign_list.html**

```
<a href="{% url 'campaigns:tweets:tweet_list' campaignId=campaign.campaignId %}" type="button" class="btn btn-default"></a>
```

**campaigns/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',

    url(
        r'^(?P<campaignId>\d+?)/tweets/',
        include('providers.twitter.urls', namespace='tweets')
    ),
```

**twitter/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from .views import TweetListView


urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(
        r'^list/$',
        TweetListView.as_view(),
        name='tweet_list'
    ),
```

**twitter/views.py**

```
class TweetListView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView): # CampaignOwnerPermission,
    '''Displays TwitterPosts relevant to a Campaign; The campaignId variable
    is passed to get_object request method from the campaign_list page.'''

    template_name = 'twitter/stream.html'
    paginate_by = settings.PAGINATE_BY_VIEWS
    context_object_name = 'tweets'
    page_kwarg = 'page'
    object = None

    def get_object(self):
        if self.object is None:
            # Return all TwitterPosts for Campaign designated by campaignId
            self.object = GetTwitterPostsForCampaign(self.campaignId)

        return self.object

    def paginate_queryset(self, object, store, page_size):
        paginator = TweetPaginator(
            object, store, page_size
        )

        page = self.request.GET.get(self.page_kwarg) or 1

        try:
            page_number = int(page)
        except ValueError:
            if page == 'last':
                page_number = paginator.num_pages
            elif page == 'first':
                page_number = 1
            else:
                raise Http404(_('Page is not found.'))
        try:
            page = paginator.page(page_number)
            return (paginator, page, page.object_list, page.has_other_pages())
        except InvalidPage as e:
            raise Http404(
                _('Invalid page (%(page_number)s): %(message)s') % {
                    'page_number': page_number,
                    'message': str(e)
                }
            )

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        object = self.get_object()
        page_size = self.paginate_by
        context_object_name = self.context_object_name

        if page_size:
            paginator, page, queryset, is_paginated = self.paginate_queryset(
                object, self.kwargs['store'], page_size
            )
            context = {
                'paginator': paginator,
                'page_obj': page,
                'is_paginated': is_paginated,
                'object_list': queryset
            }
        else:
            raise InvalidPage

        if context_object_name is not None:
            context[context_object_name] = queryset

        context.update(kwargs)

        context['campaign'] = self.campaign

        return super(TweetStoreListView, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been easier if you had posted the full traceback, which would have shown exactly where the error was occurring.

Nevertheless, it's probably happening in your view's `get_object` method, the third line of which should be:

```
self.object = GetTwitterPostsForCampaign(self.kwargs['campaignId'])
```